# Dired+ not loading from the init file on Windows

Tags: init-file, dired

I use Emacs 24.4 on Ubuntu and Windows with virtually identical init files. The following snippet is not loading correctly on Windows:

```
(require 'dired+)
(diredp-toggle-find-file-reuse-dir 1)
```

The intent is to use the same buffer while navigating folders in `dired+`. It is working as expected on my home machine running Ubuntu, but it gives the following error on the work computer running Windows:

```
File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, dired+
```

I do have `dired+` installed, and it runs when evaluating the same section in Emacs after it has opened. However, it's not being recognized during startup. Has anyone faced this problem with `dired+`, and is there a way to load it properly on Windows?

Comment: Since you have accepted an answer, presumably the problem is solved. You might want to indicate what was wrong - either in what you were doing or in what you were understanding, to further help others.

Comment: @Drew My mistake was not calling `(package-initialize)` earlier in the init file, though it worked on Ubuntu. Is this comment indicative enough, or is it better to include an edit or an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few things to check when debugging why an installed package is not found by emacs:

- Install the package using the in-built package manager.
- Ensure that the parent folder of the package's installed folder is set to the `package-user-dir` variable (this is set to `~/.emacs.d/elpa` by default).
- You then need to do `(package-initialize)` to load the packages in that path and activate them.

> package-initialize is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function
>   in `package.el'.
>
> (package-initialize &optional NO-ACTIVATE)
>
> For more information check the manuals.
>
> Load Emacs Lisp packages, and activate them.
>   The variable `package-load-list' controls which packages to load.
>   If optional arg NO-ACTIVATE is non-nil, don't activate packages.